# Django: Getting data associated with logged in user.

Tags: python, django

After logging in, the user has access to a set of drafts they created. These are stored in the following:

```
class Draft(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.TextField()
```

The user should be able to go to `/drafts` to access their drafts. How can I use `request.user` to filter through the drafts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your view you would do:

```
drafts = Draft.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

and then return drafts to your template and loop through it.

Answer (score 3):

```
Draft.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator for your view function and filter drafts with `user=request.user` query.